# How to upload images directly to MySQL database using laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel 6 and have made a simple blog website, however i am very confused on to how i can add an image directly to the MySQL database. I don't accept user input on my site so i want to post the images directly to the database. Please guide me on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you want to put images as a `blob` column in MySQL? usually putting them on disk with only path in the database is a better practice.

Comment: Can you guide me how i can i do this(in simple terms)?

Comment: As @Isigiel said in his answer. take a look at the file system in laravel. After you make a disk (or use one of the already exist by default) you can go there and put a file. then go to your database and put it's path in the column. It should be relative to the disk root indicated inside `config/filesystems.php` later on you can use `Storage::disk('your disk name')->file($database_row->filepath)` to get your file

Comment: What path should i put in my database and how?

Comment: The path of the file you've put on the disk :-) , how? since you don't accept user input just open your database editor, go to your table, and write the path!

Comment: Thanks will give it a go!

Comment: I tried but i could't figure it out. Could you please give me a sample code as to how i can do iT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to store files directly in the database for example by converting them to base64 strings, that's definitely not good practice.
I suggest reading Laravel's docs on files https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem to see how you can use files stored on the file system for your project.

I am confused by your need for a database if you're not accepting any input, but that's probably another thing.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I heard that the laravel's file system is not a very efficient way of storing media files. is that correct? By the way i am creating an article posting website where only admins can write and publish articles and the viewers can only read them.